# Making custom cursors on Ubuntu 20.10

Tags: 20.04, customization, cursor-theme

I want to create a custom theme with custom cursors on Ubuntu 20.10, but all tutorials/instructions I've found are at least 10 years old and don't work. Any tips?

Answer (score 1):

It can't answer your question in detail, however, the following approach might be useful to you.

If you take a look at [gnome-look.org](https://www.gnome-look.org/p/1445634/) you'll find the "cursor" theme section on the second position to the left side. In the provided link the author of that particular cursor-theme (submitted on 2020-11-15) and therefore fairly recent mentioned in his description below the preview:

> This Cursor is built with [clickgen](https://github.com/ful1e5/clickgen) and render with the [puppeteer](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/).

- [clickgen](https://github.com/ful1e5/clickgen/blob/main/README.md) is (an) API for building X11 and Windows Cursors from .png files. clickgen is using anicursorgen and xcursorgen under the hood.
- [Puppeteer](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/README.md) is a Node library which provides a high-level API to control Chrome or Chromium over the DevTools Protocol. Puppeteer runs headless by default, but can be configured to run full (non-headless) Chrome or Chromium

So you might look into those two applications and/or directly get in contact with that community for detailed information - who better is there.