# Using .cur cursor on Ubuntu?

Tags: cursor

I know you can install cursors from gnome-look and use them via gnome tweaks.

I was wondering if there was a way (like mousecape for mac), to use custom cursors, like for example a .cur cursor from here: http://www.rw-designer.com/cursor-set/pencil-by-piggeh. How can I use the cursor on the link?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert the `.cur` files to [`xcursor` (X11 cursor) format](https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.7/doc/man/man3/Xcursor.3.xhtml). You can do it e.g. with the little `python` tool [win2xcur](https://pypi.org/project/win2xcur/).

See [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/823656/where-are-cursor-icons-stored-on-ubuntu-16-04) and/or [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1293655/making-custom-cursors-on-ubuntu-20-10) question on how to create (and use) your custom theme. See also the [freedesktop specifications](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Specifications/cursor-spec/) for th cursor file names.